# Email log monitring using Watcher and Kibana to trigger every minute for duration last minute

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Need to create watcher in Kibana that triggers every minute and searches for specific log(s) within last one minute and shoots and email accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Was able to create below in advanced watch

```
{   "trigger": {
    "schedule": {
      "interval": "1m"
    }   },   "input": {
    "search": {
      "request": {
        "search_type": "query_then_fetch",
        "indices": [
          "*"
        ],
        "rest_total_hits_as_int": true,
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": {
                "range": {
                  "@timestamp": {
                    "gte": "{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}||-1m",
                    "lte": "{{ctx.trigger.scheduled_time}}",
                    "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }   },   "condition": {
    "script": {
      "source": "if (ctx.payload.hits.total > params.threshold) { return true; } return false;",
      "lang": "painless",
      "params": {
        "threshold": 0
      }
    }   },   "actions": {
    "email_action": {
      "email": {
        "profile": "standard",
        "attachments": {
          "attached_data": {
            "data": {
              "format": "json"
            }
          }
        },
        "to": [
          "myemail@gmail.com"
        ],
        "subject": "Winlog Errors Encountered {{ctx.payload.hits.total}} logs",
        "body": {
          "text": "Too many logs in the system, see attached data"
        }
      }
    }   } }
```